# How to print alphabet from A - Z. Each letter will be taken 3 second for print, only A will take 0 second?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, if-statement

When I try to execute by for loop & setTimeout method then got the output **undefined**. Then i tried to below method

```
var alphAbet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']


setTimeout(function loop() {
    console.log(alphAbet.shift());

    if (alphAbet.length){
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);
    }
}, 3000);
```

From **A to Z** all letters execute after **3 seconds**. But based on the condition letter **A** will not take any time.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Get rid of the outer setTimeout. Just define, then call loop()

Answer (score 1):

Replaced 'A' from your array list and added a window load function , hope it will help you .

```
var alphAbet = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
        console.log("A");
    })
    setTimeout(function loop() {
        console.log(alphAbet.shift());
    
        if (alphAbet.length){
            setTimeout(loop, 3000);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: both of u have correct answers, however as much as markus has a "better" answer u answered first

Comment: Only, when a load event is triggered. Will not work in node or pasted directly in browser console. Maybe that's what he did for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You could make loop calling itself (recursion).

```
var alphAbet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

function loop() {
    console.log(alphAbet.shift());
    if (alphAbet.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);
    }
}

loop();
```

Comment: I tried this code but result is same. Letter A took 3 seconds. But letter A will not take any time.

Comment: Just replace last line with `loop();` this way A will pop right now

Comment: @SwadipSinghoRoySoumya Oh, I thought you wanted to delay A for three seconds as well, so I added it into a setTimeout(), too. (see edits) Reverted it back. So A comes instantly, and every other letter ater 3 seconds each.

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes, B to Z can take 3 sec but A can't take this time for execute.

Comment: @SwadipSinghoRoySoumya Yes, that's why I updated the answer, back. Now it should run for you as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this way...

```js
const out = document.querySelector('p')

function* AlphaLetter( text )
 {
 for (let letter of text)
   yield letter;
 }

var gen = AlphaLetter('ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ') 

out.textContent = gen.next().value 

let refInt = setInterval(()=>
  {
  let l = gen.next()
  if (l.done) clearInterval(refInt)
  else out.textContent += l.value
  },1000)
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: A already taken time. But A can't take any time for execute.

Comment: @SwadipSinghoRoySoumya Yes, this is what is coded, A is displayed immediately then there is a delay between each letter, exactly as you requested in your question.